# How to target another element to join with another positioned element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been going through problems in positioning navbar even after the fact that its responsive. Problem comes when zooming in and zooming out (except for Mozilla), and I got no choices than asking experts for a solution because I am a noob in coding.

Chrome zoom-out: https://s31.postimg.org/kjnbou0yj/zoom_out_chrome.png

Mozilla zoom-out (also perfect in zoom-in): https://s31.postimg.org/ud3lz1i3v/zoom_out_moz.png

Basically, I want to join my navbar with another div element so that it do not move from its position and I don't know how to use :target etc, and do not even know if target will solve my problem.

My need: I just need my navbar to stick to one size. With current settings, it is working PERFECTLY with MOZILLA ONLY. I don't know why it show blank space in chrome and other browsers when zoom-out and when zoom-in. Working fine with Chrome 100% zoom and working fine with Opera 100% zoom. The problem comes when zooming in or zooming out. Again, it is working perfectly for mozilla in zooming etc, no such problems with mozilla. And my navbar is responsive too.

My guess: I think that attaching this navbar with hidden div class could solve this problem. BUT I am a complete noob in coding and I can just guess.

Here is the code of my navbar:

```
ul.pnav {
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 900px;
  height: 55px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 281px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #767676;
  z-index: 9999;
}


 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
 ul.pnav {
 top: 286px
 }  
 }


 ul.pnav li {float: left;}

 ul.pnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 3s;
  font-size: 17px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
    }

 ul.pnav li a:hover {background-color: #111;}

 ul.pnav li.icon {display: none;}

  @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
   ul.pnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
   ul.pnav li.icon {
     float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
} 

  @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
   ul.pnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    ul.pnav.responsive li.icon {
     position: absolute;
      right: 0;
     top: 0;
     }
     ul.pnav.responsive li {
      float: none;
      display: inline;
      }
   ul.pnav.responsive li a {
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
   }
  }
```

I have this in html as a code:

```
    <ul class="pnav">
     <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
     <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
   </li>
   </ul>
```

This is div class to which I want to attach navbar.

```
  <div class="fornavbar"></div>
```

I don't know how to proceed further, please help.

Comment: 1. "I want to join my navbar with another div element so that it do not move from its position", where do you want that div to be positioned exactly? 2. "My need: I just need my navbar to stick to one size." As far as I can tell, it is always the same size?

Comment: @LinusAronsson Hello, sorry for bad word choice. I meant "zoom in and zoom out issue when using the word 'size' ".

I just updated the first post with two images, please see them to get where I want div to be positioned. I'll just add "div" at the current place of navbar, and want to target this "div class" and make navbar attached completely with this div class with some offset options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8qepe4gw/2/

In order for them to align together you just simply put them both inside of a common div like this (.container),

```
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="pnav">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
    </ul>
   <div class="fornavbar"></div>
</div>
```

And then you assign a width to the .container, and then you can give both the .pnav and .fornavbar a width of 100% so they stretch all the way out inside of the container, as in they have the same width.

Now the reason why it only worked in firefox is probably because of this part of the code:

```
 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
   ul.pnav {
   top: 286px
  }  
}
```

Because  @-moz-document only targets firefox.

It's still gonna work in all browsers now though with the new code I added in the fiddle so you shouldn't have to worry about it, perhaps even delete that part of the CSS code(?).

Comment: Thanks Linus. You completely understood my problem and a great solution indeed.. Thumbs up and best wishes for you.